# Install VS2015 DotNetCore RC2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, .net-core-rc2

I wanted to update the Aspnet5 rc1 to DotNetcode RC2. I am unable to uninstall rc1. If I install rc3, I get following error:

Here is the log:

```
[0584:098C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_rc2_14.msi' to: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\{486C853B-822E-452D-9046-814A51B05A27}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed'
[0584:098C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_rc2_14.msi' to working path: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\{486C853B-822E-452D-9046-814A51B05A27}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed'
[0584:098C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]e313: Failed to acquire payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed to working path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\{486C853B-822E-452D-9046-814A51B05A27}\AspNetCoreLocalFeed, error: 0x80070642.
[3208:146C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\d61fae17-5f78-3fe8-8203-ded682de23e3\
[3208:146C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]i351: Removing cached package: SetupBlocked_Install, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ff930c3d-5c12-31e7-bf69-57d7bd4b56db\
[3208:0A94][2016-06-09T23:30:46]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22041006-8484-4b8d-a13c-40189695de2f}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[3208:0A94][2016-06-09T23:30:46]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{22041006-8484-4b8d-a13c-40189695de2f}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0584:303C][2016-06-09T23:30:46]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070666, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

I have rc1, and I was not able to uninstall it. Here is the log for the same.

```
[2E30:28F8][2016-06-09T23:33:54]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[336C:2A04][2016-06-09T23:33:54]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}\AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe
[336C:07E4][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0
[336C:2A04][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to wait for operation complete.
[336C:2A04][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container.
[336C:2A04][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container: WixAttachedContainer.
[336C:2A04][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}\5EC497D30F70028E227BD065DF4547A6F024E1E1, error: 0x80070001.
[336C:21E8][2016-06-09T23:33:54]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[2E30:28F8][2016-06-09T23:33:54]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[2E30:28F8][2016-06-09T23:33:54]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[336C:21E8][2016-06-09T23:33:54]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070001, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error, but was able to uninstall the ASP.NET RC1.

I followed the link it says it can't download and successfully download the file and installed it... but now I'm not sure what state my install is in.  It shows up in the Programs and Features window, as installed... but..

Comment: I had to uninstall VS2015 and reinstall the same. I think I messed up while installing rc2. This resolved my issue. try using msi from here https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows if that helps!

Answer (score 4):

It could also be related to VS 2015 Update 3.  If you installed Update 3 first, then a [known issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3-rc) says that there is failure to remove registry keys related to the VC++ redistributables.

You need to go into Programs and Features and right-click->Change->Repair both the x64 and x86 versions of the latest Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (version 14.0.24123)

This worked for me and I was able then to install both the .net core RC 2 and the VS tooling preview successfully.

Comment: That could be correct, as I had also installed VS2015 update first. I cannot verify this and mark as answer, as I already uninstalled and reinstalled VS2015 for this.