# .NET Core SDK Installer failed to install on windows 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I setting up my build server for CI using Jenkins. I am trying to install .NET Core SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download
However i tried executing downloaded `DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe` i get unspecified error
[image]

and here is complete log

```
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0D7DA4AD-993A-4038-A544-14369A3FAF40}\.cr\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Initializing string variable 'DOTNETHOME' to value '[ProgramFiles6432Folder]dotnet'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Initializing string variable 'BUNDLEMONIKER' to value 'Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003131'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\codescriptor\Downloads\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003131 (x64)'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[07E8:0B8C][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[07E8:0B8C][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '1.0.0.3131'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VCRedist_KeyExists' to value 0
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i052: Condition '(VCRedist_KeyExists AND VCRedist_KeyValue >= "v14.0.23506.00")' evaluates to false.
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i101: Detected package: VC_redist.x64.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i101: Detected package: dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i101: Detected package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i101: Detected package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i101: Detected package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:36]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[07E8:0B8C][2016-09-19T12:09:41]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[07E8:0B8C][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i200: Plan begin, 5 packages, action: Install
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VC_redist.x64.exe
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_VC_redist.x64.exe' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_000_VC_redist.x64.exe.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_001_dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi_rollback.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_001_dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_002_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_002_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_003_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_003_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_004_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_.NET_Core_1.0.1_-_SDK_1.0.0_Preview_2-003131_(x64)_20160919120936_004_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log'
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i201: Planned package: VC_redist.x64.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i201: Planned package: dotnet_dev_win_x64.1.0.0_preview2_003131.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i201: Planned package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i201: Planned package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i201: Planned package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i300: Apply begin
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:45]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:46]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:46]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:46]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:46]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:46]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:47]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\.be\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003131.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-003131.exe'
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:47]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, version: 1.0.0.3131
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:47]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:47]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:47]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:47]e000: Error 0x80072f07: Failed to send request to URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:47]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:47]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:50]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:50]e000: Error 0x80072f07: Failed to send request to URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:50]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:50]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:53]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:53]e000: Error 0x80072f07: Failed to send request to URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:53]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:53]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:56]e000: Error 0x80072f07: Failed to send request to URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:56]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:56]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed to acquire payload from: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409' to working path: 'C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[07E8:0A40][2016-09-19T12:09:56]e313: Failed to acquire payload: VC_redist.x64.exe to working path: C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{0286308F-D022-4BF4-ABB5-2740FCDC1C23}\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80072f76.
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Cache thread exited unexpectedly.
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i352: Removing cached bundle: {003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}\
[0D20:07B4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[07E8:0FE4][2016-09-19T12:09:56]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80072f76, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Note:
On the build server I have already installed .Net 4.6.2 because I have few other projects which are targeting 4.6.2 and 4.5.2.
Also note that I **do not** have VS 2015 installed on build server, however i **do have** VS 2013 installed on the build server.
I am not sure if i also need to install VS 2015 before i install .Net core SDK

**Update1**
Based on google search `0x80072f76` error is related to internet connection however the connection is working on the server, thats how I downloaded the installer in the first place.

**Update 2**
So I fixed `0x80072f76` issue by allowing IE to download file. But now I get different error `0x80070490 element not found` with the following log. *(note I have only included log from the error line)*

```
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e310: Failed to verify payload: VC_redist.x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e314: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe from working path: C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{A13540BB-FD46-428C-91CC-F1E279981B20}\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490.
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:36]e349: Application requested retry of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, encountered error: 0x80070490. Retrying...
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:36]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\codescriptor\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:39]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e310: Failed to verify payload: VC_redist.x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e314: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe from working path: C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{A13540BB-FD46-428C-91CC-F1E279981B20}\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490.
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:41]e349: Application requested retry of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, encountered error: 0x80070490. Retrying...
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:41]w343: Prompt for source of package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, path: C:\Users\codescriptor\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:44]i338: Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, download from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&amp;clcid=0x409
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e310: Failed to verify payload: VC_redist.x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[08B8:0DF0][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
[04DC:0990][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e314: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe from working path: C:\Users\CODESC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\{A13540BB-FD46-428C-91CC-F1E279981B20}\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490.
[04DC:0C44][2016-09-19T13:11:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Cache thread exited unexpectedly.
[08B8:0BFC][2016-09-19T13:11:45]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[08B8:0BFC][2016-09-19T13:11:45]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}
[08B8:0BFC][2016-09-19T13:11:45]i352: Removing cached bundle: {003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}\
[08B8:0BFC][2016-09-19T13:11:45]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{003165d2-8bbe-4e00-a6a2-631fb72c1a52}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[04DC:0C44][2016-09-19T13:11:45]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070490, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: Your log is riddled with network errors. Try downloading `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&clcid=0x409` in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @vcsjones I can download it with google chrome but not with IE. With IE I am getting error `Your current setting do not allow this file to be downloaded`. However as I mentioned I have download the actual installer (using chrome) and now when installer is trying to get required packages I'm getting `0x80072f76` error. I'm not sure what IE has to do with this

Comment: Look at the log. The log says the installer is trying to download that file, and failing: "Failed attempt to download URL". The installer is likely using the same download "permissions" as IE. Your installer is a "thin" installer. That is, it doesn't include a full installer, just one that kicks off other downloads and installs.

Comment: "Failed to verify signature of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe" What the installer downloaded isn't what it expected to download. It couldn't validate the download.

Comment: @vcsjones I saw that but how to resolve that? I have downloaded the installer from MS site

Comment: I found the answer here https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/271

Comment: I also encountered the same error while trying to install the SDK on Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5. The answer is in LP13's link -- download and install VC_redist.x64.exe from `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460`

Comment: this answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739470/install-vs2015-dotnetcore-rc2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `0x80070490 element not found`  issue I found the answer here https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/271

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1: Manually Install `VC_redist.x64.exe`

1. Download and install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145).
2. Re-install .NET Core SDK

#### Solution 2: Turn off IE ESC Temporarily:

This solution worked for me as well. [Here](http://prajwaldesai.com/disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)'s how to disable IE Enhanced Security Configuration:

1. Open Server Manager.
2. Click "Local Server" at the left side.
3. On the right side of Server Manager if you see IE Enhanced Security Configuration is "On", click "On".
4. When a new windows pops up, turn IE ESC off for both Administrator and Users.
5. Re-install .NET Core SDK.
6. Turn IE ESC on after installation.

Comment: this answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739470/install-vs2015-dotnetcore-rc2

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not an issue with the installer per se, but rather with your IE config options.

Here is a solution from [Microsoft Community:](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/error-message-your-current-security-settings-do/59cc236d-7baf-4552-92ff-b34b9a6942aa)

> I would suggest you to enable the file download in Internet Explorer.
>
> a.    Open Internet Explorer.
>
> b.    Click Tools and then options.
>
> c.    Click on the security tab.
>
> d.    Select the Internet Zone.
>
> e.    Click on the Custom Level Button and then scroll down to Download.
>
> f.     Make sure to enable File download.
>
> g.    Click Apply and Ok
>
> h.    Restart Internet Explorer and check if that helps.

Doing the above steps should solve the problem. You can validate by opening up IE and trying to download any file and confirming it is able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Even i got the same **error** while installing 32 bit **.netcore SDK**
i just  **installed Visual C++ Redistributable Packages** from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145 and restarted my machine.

and the problem was solved.!!