# Failed to install "DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3" to VS2015 Update3

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have my VS2015 update 3 successfully installed but failed to install the latest Net Core 1.0.1 Tooling preview2. I tried a couple of time to repair it but still have the same issue.

I looked into the log file and I found this:

> [1F88:1A48][2016-12-17T21:34:04]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt
>   to download URL:
>   'https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_69.msi'

I copied this link to browser and it can be downloaded though. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

I reinstalled the entire VS and run the setup from cmd `DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` but no luck.

The entire log file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=35547800629021061525

[image: error]

Comment: May be this is related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578699/net-core-sdk-installer-failed-to-install-on-windows-2012-r2-standard

Answer (score 1):

one of the packages failed to download from Microsoft. I downloaded it manually and executed it. this worked for me:

- download file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460&clcid=0x409
- rename file downloaded to vc_redist.x64.exe(if needed)
- double-click on it in windows explorer
- once this finishes, rerun DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

hope this helps someone